# Iterate through list, displaying whole list

Tags: list, loops, search, struct, scheme

I am trying to write a simple search through a list of structs. My current code is mean to take in a planet and search through my existing little list and find the matching struct and display the mass of that planet. Currently using the Dr. Racket compiler it displays the whole list. I am not sure why and would appreciate any help.

```
#lang scheme
(define-struct celestialbody
  (
   name
   mass
   radius
  )
  #:transparent
)

(define bigG .00000000006673)

(define (newCelestialBody name mass radius)
  (make-celestialbody name mass radius))

(define SolarSystem
  (list
   (newCelestialBody "Sun" 1988550000000000000000000000000 695700)
   (newCelestialBody "Mercury" 330110000000000000000000 2439.7)
   (newCelestialBody "Venus" 4867500000000000000000000 6051.8)
   (newCelestialBody "Earth" 5972370000000000000000000 6371)
   (newCelestialBody "Moon" 7342000000000000000000 1737.1)
   (newCelestialBody "Mars" 641710000000000000000000 3389.5)
   (newCelestialBody "Jupiter" 1898600000000000000000000000 69911)
   (newCelestialBody "Saturn" 568360000000000000000000000 58232)
   (newCelestialBody "Uranus" 86810000000000000000000000 25362)
   (newCelestialBody "Neptune" 102430000000000000000000000 24622)
  )
)

(define (find-mass planet system)
  (if(empty? list)
      (#f)
      (if(string-ci=? (celestialbody-name (first system)) planet)
         (celestialbody-mass (first system)) 
         (find-mass planet (rest system))
      )
   )
)
```

Comment: Please indent the code correctly: you should not leave parentheses alone by themselves in a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base case in the search procedure is wrong, and you should use `cond` instead of nesting `if`s. Other than that, the code looks fine:

```
(define (find-mass planet system)
  (cond ((empty? system) #f)
        ((string-ci=? (celestialbody-name (first system)) planet)
         (celestialbody-mass (first system)))
        (else (find-mass planet (rest system)))))
```

For example:

```
(find-mass "Saturn" SolarSystem)
=> 568360000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked. Very quick response. I was actually trying to figure it out based on your response to Tim from like 3 years ago.